# Can a Visual Studio Addin determine which version of Visual Studio it is running in?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-addins

I am writing a Visual Studio Addin in VB.net, and I want to be able to tell which version of Visual Studio the Addin is running in. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use `DTE.Version`, documentation from [MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/envdte._dte.version.aspx)